# File drag and drop not firing in IE9?

Tags: drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-9

Drag and drop files does not seem to work in IE8, IE9.
Using ajax file upload,in firefox it is working. but IE8, IE9 fails.

Is there any alternate for **DRAG AND DROP** File upload in IE9 ??

Answer (score 0):

As I know, its working with combo, but you can do some modifcation in toolkit to make it working, See details in below link:
AjaxFileUpload: Drag and Drop is not working on IE10 for Windows 7
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27369
Please note: Since the site is not hosted by Microsoft, the link may change without notice. Microsoft does not guarantee the accuracy of this information.
The Drag and Drop facility is currently expected to work with IE 11 and higher. Internet Explorer 10 and below do not implement the HTML5 File API which is required for drag and drop file uploads.
The workaround is to use the conventional method (non-Drag & Drop) to upload files.
Meanwhile, you can post to IE development forum to get more insights.
As IE development forum focuses on questions about web development including HTML, CSS and Script for Internet Explorer, your issue can be fixed efficiently.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/home
Hope it helps.